# What type of a literary device is this?

Tags: literary-techniques

> A murdering thief or a thieving murderer.

I have looked up all possible literary devices, and can't seem to find one...

Comment: *Antimetabole*, perhaps.

Comment: @snailboat: why perhaps?

Comment: @PeterShor Well, I looked it up briefly, saw "in successive clauses", shrugged, and decided that the people who know about things like antimetabole could sort it out.

Comment: This is a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem, as this question keeps getting asked over and over and over again, but each time with a different example phrase. So you can only really search for the answer if you already *know* the answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is an example of *chiasmus*, which is

> 1. Repetition of ideas in inverted order
> 2. Repetition of grammatical structures in inverted order (not to be mistaken with antimetabole, in which identical words are repeated and inverted).

See [here](http://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/lit_terms_C.html) or any other reputable source. (One of my favorites, from which the above is drawn, is [Silva Rhetoricae](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/).